# Mr. Bean's Ridiculous Way to Work

Tags: visual, optimization, mazes

If you saw Mr. Bean as a kid, or ever, you know how crazy and unbelievable he is. In this scenario, Mr. Bean lives in the bottom left house and works for the school at the left, but he always takes the longest and most inefficient way. Your job is to find the longest and most unbelievable way he can get to work.

Rules Mr. Bean must follow:

- He can't go on the same road more than 3 times.
- The arrows are showing that the road around the arrow is a one-way.
- If a road does not have any arrows, it is 2-way.
- He can't cross any police station more than once. (Because he is wanted for [not paying toll fees](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YPVqy1kFy18))

Note: This is just the start to a list of puzzles, so don't worry about the other images.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBplg.jpg]

Also I do not know what tags to put for this so please fee free to add tags that this puzzle may fall under it.

Comment: btw quick question. How many of you have seen mr bean?

Comment: For the purposes of this question, how do you define "most unbelievable"? Is it just "longest"? Also, I assume the police *cars* don't count as police *stations*? (Or if they do, what counts as "crossing" the one in the middle?)

Comment: I mean longest also the police car is the station because I could not find a good clipart for station

Comment: by crossing I mean like you cant be on the same road the station is on only one time. an example is the middle rectangle is fully around the station so u can only go once. Hopefully this clarifies things

Comment: I love Mr Bean! There is a funny new netflix series with him called Man vs Bee. Check it out!

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky I will try it but imo nothing tops Mr bean and other shows from the late 1990s to early 2000's like Everyone loves raymond in terms of comedy with an exception of a few shows

Comment: @VarunW. agree they don't make them the same anymore. The closest is probably Big Bang Theory. I really like everyone loves Raymond too.

Comment: Does every single edge in the network count  as a separate road? E.g. for the wide top road, is this actually composed of 3 separate roads? If not, is it just every vertical/horizontal line? Is the police station in the middle adjacent to all 4 sides?

Comment: @LukasRotter The top section (consisting of 2 schools, hospital, tollgate, station) is made of 7 roads (2 vertical, one to station, one in between, one to the big school, one to the small school, and one to the hospital). Is the police station in the middle adjacent to all 4 sides? (Yes)